# Postfix rewrites data from

Tags: email, postfix

I have a strange problem in my infrastructure. If i receive a mail which has the data from field encoded with base64 for example postfix decides to add my domain to the encoded data from.

For example Data From is `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbQ==` which comes out as `dGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbQ==@domain.com`

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the From field?

Comment: Yes, as i said in the message :)

Comment: You said Data From, which doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Yes ist does since there are two "froms". The envelope Sender (from) and the From in the Body or Data of the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop postfix appening myorigin by using:
append_at_myorigin = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
in your config.

For further reference and security implications see:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/postfix-the-definitive/0596002122/ch04s07.html